# Running into [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Integer at runtime

Tags: java, arrays, casting

At runtime, I keep running into the error above when trying to make a List<Integer[]>  to an Integer[].

```
    public static Integer[] findKthLargest(List<Integer[]> list, int k) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        
        Integer[] arr = (Integer[]) list.toArray();
        insertionSort(arr, new ArrayComparator());
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        
        return arr[k];
```

I've tried casting the List<Integer[]> into an Object[] and then to an Integer[] but I run into the same error. I can't change the method header

I haven't finished the rest of the method's implementation yet so I placed a println to see if it'd provide me with roughly the results I expected.

Comment: What line are you getting that on?

Comment: You're expecting to be able to convert a `List<Integer[]>` (that is, a list of arrays of integers) to an `Integer[]` (that is, a single array of integers)?

Comment: I'm getting this runtime error on 
Integer[] arr = (Integer[]) list.toArray();

Comment: *"I can't change the method header"* — Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to *have* to do that with something like

```
Integer[][] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[0][]);
```

or use streams.

Comment: Are you sure that this works ?

Comment: The OP seems a little unclear on how `List<Integer[]>` translates into an `Integer[]` versus an `Integer[][]`.  This version seems pretty clearly what they want, though.

Comment: Thank you. This implementation was what ended up working for me

`Integer[][] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()][]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this:

```
Integer[] arr = (Integer[]) list.toArray();
```

If I understand what you want to do, you need something like this:

```
Integer[] arr = list.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Example:

```
List<Integer[]> list = List.of(new Integer[]{1,2,3}, new Integer[]{4,5,5});
Integer[] arr = list.stream()
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```